# Check if a time period is included in another time period

Tags: sql

In my db i have many record, with start date and length of that time of period.

For example

```
id start_date           lenght
1  2013-01-01 00:00:00   20
2  2013-02-30 00:00:00   10
3  2013-01-20 00:00:00   3
```

So i can easily get the end date.

Now if the user gave me any period of time, how can I control if that period is included in one of the time period that I have in the db?

Thank you.

Comment: So `length` is in units of days? And if we add that number of days onto `start_date`, does that identify the last day of that period, or the day *after* the last day of the period? E.g. does period one include `2013-01-21`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list using a `where` clause and the `date` functions:

```
select *
from t
where XXX between start_date and date_add(start_date, interval length day);
```

EDIT:

The above is for one date.  If the user gives two date, XXX and YYY, then this is what you want for any overlap:

```
select *
from t
where XXX <= date_add(start_date, interval length day) and
      YYY >= start_date;
```

That is, the period the user gives you starts before the end of the interval and the period ends after the start of the interval.

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry but another bunt,for XXX you mean each day from the period the user inserts?

Comment: @Simo . . . I modified the question for two dates.  When asking a question, it is a good idea to include sample data and desired results.  These tend to be the best way to express what is needed.